# The precedence of polling of the consumer in batch mode

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

```
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records = 2000 //each record of size 5kb takes 100 ms so to process entire batch takes 500 sec i.e 8 min 20 sec
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms = 900000 //15 min
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.fetch.max.wait.ms = 600000 //10 min
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.partition.fetch.bytes = 10485760 //10MB
spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-min-size = 5242880  // fetch.min.bytes - 5mb
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency  = 1
```

With the above configuration the consumer is continously polling the records its respective intervals like sometimes 2 mins, 3 mins eventhough  fetch.max.wait.ms has been set it as as 10 min.
How this is happening ? May i know the precedence of polling ? is it based on the  max-poll-records, fetch.max.wait.ms ,max.partition.fetch.bytes or fetch-min-size ?

EDIT:
I tried to maximize the below attribute values to fetch maximum records, but still seeing only 200 to 300 records are getting processed.

```
     spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms = 900000 //15 min
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records = 2000 //each record of size 5kb takes 100 ms so to process entire batch, takes 2000*100 ms =200sec i.e 3 min 20 sec which is way less than the max poll interval (10min)
    spring.kafka.consumer.properties.fetch.max.wait.ms = 600000 //10 min
    spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.partition.fetch.bytes = 20971520
    //20MB
    spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-min-size = 104857600 // fetch.min.bytes - 20mb
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the records are exactly 5kb, the poll will return when 1k records are received or 10 minutes elapse, whichever happens first.

You will only ever get `max.poll.records` if they are immediately available.

**EDIT**

It looks to me like these "smaller" batches are the remnants of the previous fetch; with this code:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So68201599Application {


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So68201599Application.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So68201599Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so68201599", topics = "so68201599", autoStartup = "false")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecords<?, ?> in) {
        log.info("" + in.count() + "\n"
                + in.partitions().stream()
                    .map(part -> "" + part.partition() + "(" + in.records(part).size() + ")")
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so68201599").partitions(10).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        String msg = new String(new byte[1024*5]);
        return args -> {
            List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
            IntStream.range(0, 9000).forEach(i -> futures.add(template.send("so68201599", msg)));
            futures.forEach(fut -> {
                try {
                    fut.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            log.info("Sent");
            registry.getListenerContainer("so68201599").start();
        };
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records = 2000
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.fetch.max.wait.ms = 10000
spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-min-size = 10240000

spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

spring.kafka.listener.type=batch
```

I get

```
2021-07-08 15:04:11.131  INFO 45792 --- [o68201599-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So68201599Application   : 2000
[1(201), 0(201), 5(201), 4(201), 3(201), 2(201), 9(201), 8(201), 7(201), 6(191)]
2021-07-08 15:04:11.137  INFO 45792 --- [o68201599-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So68201599Application   : 10
[6(10)]
2021-07-08 15:04:21.170  INFO 45792 --- [o68201599-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So68201599Application   : 1809
[1(201), 0(201), 5(201), 4(201), 3(201), 2(201), 9(201), 8(201), 7(201)]
2021-07-08 15:04:21.214  INFO 45792 --- [o68201599-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So68201599Application   : 2000
[1(201), 0(201), 5(201), 4(201), 3(201), 2(201), 9(201), 8(201), 7(201), 6(191)]
2021-07-08 15:04:21.215  INFO 45792 --- [o68201599-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So68201599Application   : 10
[6(10)]
2021-07-08 15:04:31.248  INFO 45792 --- [o68201599-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So68201599Application   : 1809
[1(201), 0(201), 5(201), 4(201), 3(201), 2(201), 9(201), 8(201), 7(201)]
2021-07-08 15:04:41.267  INFO 45792 --- [o68201599-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So68201599Application   : 1083
[1(27), 0(87), 5(189), 4(93), 3(114), 2(129), 9(108), 8(93), 7(42), 6(201)]
2021-07-08 15:04:51.276  INFO 45792 --- [o68201599-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So68201599Application   : 201
[6(201)]
2021-07-08 15:05:01.279  INFO 45792 --- [o68201599-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So68201599Application   : 78
[6(78)]
```

I don't know why the second and the three penultimate fetches timed out, though.

Comment: "Assuming the records are exactly 5kb, the poll will return when 1k records are received or 10 minutes elapse, whichever happens first." - 
Do you mean 5kb*1000 records = 5mb ~ fetch-min-size (5mb) ?  Is the poll happening due to the first 1000 records size matches with fetch-min-size (5mb)  ? can fetch-min-size be increased to 20mb ?

Comment: Yes. Actually `5k x 1024` but you can set the min size to whatever you want.

Comment: From 5k*1024 , May I know what is 1024 ? What would be the best combination if we want to process more no of records or long wait on poll?

Comment: 5mb is `5120*1024=5242880` (5k*1k).

Comment: Hi @Gary, i tried maximize the record count to process with all the above configuration attributes. I would need to hold the poll for 10 min or 2000 records count.  The reason behind this is , we are consuming from a source topic (10 partitions) in which it has millions of records getting stacked up in a day. we need to process the records in sync with that source topic.

Comment: The only tools available are `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms`.

Comment: are these attributes fetch.min.bytes and fetch.max.wait.ms depends on any broker level attributes?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Looks like one explanation for the short batches is records from the previous fetch that exceeded the max. But it does seem a bit erratic. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: I think once the first batch of records gets processed, then it should poll next set of batch  of records. but it not happening like that .. is there any issue with the api (spring-kafka-2.3.8- Release)? can i opt any lower version?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Spring - this is how the `kafka-clients` `KafkaConsumer` behaves - Spring just delegates to that code. I suggest you ask for clarification from the Kafka folks, perhaps post a question on one of their mailing lists (user or dev).

Comment: is there any work around right now @Gary?  can i introduce the some idleTimebetweenPolls configuration?

Comment: No; it doesn't make a difference; except it adds more delays between getting batches of records. We are at the mercy of the `kafka-clients` code. I got identical results as those above, in terms of record counts on each poll (just that the polls were further apart).

Comment: I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13054) - let's see what they have to say.

Comment: Looks like the problem is too few partitions; in my test if I increase the partitions to 100, I get exactly 2000 records on each poll.

Comment: Thanks @Gary for your help and raising the request on behalf of me.  But still i am confused  is ,   when more than 2000 records available in 10 partitions,  the poll should wait for the first 2000 and then next records should be retrived in second poll (after 10sec).  I have verified the same thing is happening on single partition with one consumer also.

Comment: I agree - I don't understand the algorithm; hence I opened the issue; we just have to wait for them to respond. In the meantime, it seems that increasing the partitions is a work-around - it works as expected for me with 100 partitions.

Comment: Hi Gary!! still we didnt receive any response from the jira - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13054

Comment: Sorry; there is nothing more I can do; I have no control.